# How to animate Card View to Full-Screen View(and vice versa)?

Tags: swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I've spent a lot of time trying to find a way to do this UIView work. But I couldn't find it. So I want to ask it.

[image]

In my analysis, Card views are on the View.

When I am tapping a Card View, then it spread out to the Full-Screen View.

And the full-screen view has scroll view contents.

And when I am pulling down the full-screen view, it starts to shrinks to shape of Card.

And at certain point, it is changed to a Card View automatically.

But, it seems that the images and the titles in Card View and Full-Screen View are the same.

It makes me to think that Card view and Full-Screen view are the same views.

I've searched what the code or technique was used. And I found that UITapGestureRecognizer was needed to make Card view tappable. But, I have no idea for embedding the Full-Screen view to Card view, expanding Card view and shrinking Full-Screen view. And I think these are the major and fundamental concepts to make this.

Of course, I'm not asking the full code, but I just want to know the major concept of what the code or technique was used. Then, I can study!

**Q1. How to embed Full-Screen view as Card view in a UIView?**

**Q2. How to expand Card view to Full-Screen view?**

**Q3. How to shrink Full-Screen view to Card view?**

Please help me to find what I have to study!

Thank you!

Comment: see this https://github.com/phillfarrugia/appstore-clone

Comment: do u have problem with frameworks ?

Comment: there's a really good iOS [library](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero) for view controller transitions.

Comment: See this -> https://github.com/marcosgriselli/EasyTransitions